# Recent comment for joomla 3.5

Tags: php, joomla3.5

After a lot of struggle, upgraded my joomla 1.5 to 3.5. But the old site had a recent comment section which was actually not working with SEF url.
After upgrade, I can not find any such module by searching two days in google. So I am here as the last option.

Can anyone help me by suggesting any way to create a code for this? It should work with SEF and url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify router.php to make your extension compatible with SEF URLs